# Template creation for Magnolia CMS 5.4.2

Tags: templates, magnolia

I have created a custom bundle with Magnolia 5.4.2 (using eclipse and Tomcat 7.0.12). I have created a simple "hello magnolia" template which is reflected correctly inside the resource module, but when I try to create a page I see an empty list in template section.

Comment: Hi! It may be helpful if you could provide some of your template code or such. If there's an issue with that others cannot identify it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the availability of the template script(ftl)in the below location of the MagnoliaAuthor.

WEB DEV APP-->Resources-->"Your module"-->Templates-->Pages--><"hello magnolia.ftl">